# Centering TextView in ConstraintLayout programmatically in Android (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

My code has the text view in the top right corner, after a certain amount of time I want the TextView to center. The TextView is within a ConstraintLayout. I have tried .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) and it has not worked. Was wondering if there was a way to do it without actually just making another hidden TextView that has the same contents and just pops up and hiding the other TextView after the time is up.

Comment: Why don't you post the code for your first attempt and see if others can fix it? It would be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change constraint of text view.You can change constraint programmatically.

try this:

```
 ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    set.clone(textView)
     set.connect(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                   )
                    set.connect(
                        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.RIGHT
                    )
                    set.connect(
                        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.TOP,
                        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.TOP
                    )

    set.connect(
                        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                        ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
                    )

    set.applyTo(textview)
```

if it's not working then post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just `gravity` sets the gravity of the text *within the view*. So I'm guessing that your TextView's width is `wrap_content`. In a LinearLayout you might set the width to `match_parent`. Since you're using `ConstraintLayout`, it should work if you define a constraint for the view for both the start and the end of the view (left and right).